# Django 2.1.7 Clean Way to delete a single App?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i ask myself if there is a clean way/ procedure to ask Django to delete a single app. There are Topics with the same Question but they referencing to older Versions or i missed it.

I am newbie i don´t want to mess around with the django db by simply delete the Setting.py App registration. Because I saw that in the Django DB, between all the model entries, there are also data records of migrations, sessions, data entries or how i would call it, django magic.

I am using Django 2.1.7 within VirtualEnv.

So Far my procedure.

1. Delete the `'my_old_app'` App-Registration in settings.py / `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. Change all entries in `views.py`, `urls.py` that have a connection to `my_old_app`
3. Deleting the model data of  `my_old_app`. (simply Migrate?)

Thanks, for every Information.

Comment: I think you got your procedure backwards.  The first thing I would have done would have been to remove the models classes from the app's models.py file and then I would have done `makemigrations --dry-run` and if all looks good then `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Comment: of course if this is a production/critical business Django project back everything up first.

Answer (score -1):

You could follow these steps to delete an app in a good way.

```
delete unnecessary model in `models.py` and `migrate`
delete your app name from `settings.py` in INSTALLED_APPS
delete all folder `__pycache__ `
delete all import link in `views.py`, `admin.py` end etc.
delete all link's in `urls.py` that are unnecessary
delete app's folder
```

You could make use of `--dry-run` as mentioned by @Red Cricket in comments

Comment: If you deleted the app's folder, the migration file created to remove models from database will also be deleted. So this solution is not distributable. Is there any solution ?